# Erro 404 direcionado/ou não ao Servlet. Problemas com Dispátcher

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

Estou estudando java for web (EE) e gostaria de saber se vocês poderiam ajudar a  solucionar um problema de java!

Tenho no meu web.xml uma chamada ao arquivo erro404.jsp que esta na raiz do site para filtrar páginas que não existem!

Acontece que se a página inexistente chamada estiver na raiz também, por exemplo /site/paginaInexiste.jsp, ela estará no mesmo nível que a erro404.jsp e quando erro404.jsp for chamada, todos os seus links internos (css, includes[code]) funcionarão.

Porém, quando a Página Inexistente está dentro de uma pasta qualquer da raíz, ou seja, fora do nível de erro404.jsp, exemplo `/site/pasta/paginaInexistente.jsp`, então erro404.jsp é chamada normalmente porem seus links internos não funcionam.

Experimentei enviar erros 404 para um Servlet e o mesmo realizar o `RequestDispatcher` para chamar erro404.jsp pois tanto a Servlet quanto erro404.jsp estão no mesmo nível, porém não funcionou!

### web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>imwsaogotardo</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>AdminServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>imwsaogotardo.src.controller.AdminServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AdminServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/imwsaogotardo/AdminServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ProfessorServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>imwsaogotardo.src.controller.ProfessorServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ProfessorServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/imwsaogotardo/ProfessorServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>SalaServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>imwsaogotardo.src.controller.SalaServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SalaServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/imwsaogotardo/SalaServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>UsuarioServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>imwsaogotardo.src.controller.UsuarioServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UsuarioServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/imwsaogotardo/UsuarioServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>PerguntaServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>imwsaogotardo.src.dao.pergunta.PerguntaServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>PerguntaServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/imwsaogotardo/PerguntaServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/ErrosServlet</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/ErrosServlet</location>
  </error-page>
</web-app>
```

### E na Servlet

```
package erros;

import java.io.IOException;


import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet(
            name="ErrosServlet", 
            urlPatterns={"/ErrosServlet"}
           )
public class ErrosServlet extends HttpServlet 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ErrosServlet()
    {
        super();
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)    throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        Throwable throwable = (Throwable) req.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception");
        Integer statusCode = (Integer) req.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code");

        req.setAttribute("errorType", throwable);
        req.setAttribute("statusCode", statusCode);

        //colocando o setStatus OK
        res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

        // We have to remove the exception from the request. If we do not remove the IE9 will not display out error page.
        // IE9 will think that some error created a crash inside our application if we do not remove the exception from the request.
        req.setAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception", null);
        req.setAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code", null);

        RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = null;

        if(statusCode==404)
        {
            requestDispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher("/erro404.jsp");
        }
        else if(statusCode==500)
        {
            requestDispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher("/erro500.jsp");
        }

        requestDispatcher.forward(req, res);    

    }

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)    throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        doPost(req, res);
    }   
}
```

> Obs.: Não lancei a Servet no web.xml

Será que existe algum outro recurso?

Adicionando a página de erro:

```
<jsp:useBean id="constantes" class="util.Constantes" />     
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>    
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="_global/_css/estiloSite.css" />
<title>${constantes.tituloSite}</title>
</head>
<body class="fadeIn">

 <div id="topo"> <jsp:include page="_global/topoErro.jsp" /> </div>
 <div id="meio"> <jsp:include page="erro404Conteudo.jsp" /> </div>
 <div id="mapa"> <jsp:include page="_global/mapaErro.jsp" /> </div>
 <div id="creditos"> <jsp:include page="_global/creditosErro.jsp" /> </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

A seguir erro404Conteudo.jsp

```
<div id="central">

        Esta página não existe! <br/>
        Código do Erro : ${statusCode} <br/>
        <img src="_img/editar.png">
        <a href="_global/topoErro.jsp">Editar</a>
        <jsp:include page="_global/topoErro.jsp" />

</div>
```

Bom, lembrando que o dispatcher é feito naturalmente. O erro fica por conta apenas dos links de estilo e imagens. Os hrefs e os includes ocorre normalmente!

Comment: Poderia incluir as tecnologias?(frameworks) e colocar o seu web.xml na pergunta? @CarlosRocha

Comment: Adicionei à pergunta!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei como está seu projeto e o que sugiro é uma forma de solucionar, não necessariamente a mais elegante.

Como você não postou a sua página com os links que não estão funcionando, assumo que você OU está usando caminhos fixos OU caminhos relativos, sempre a partir com caminho atual, o que em determinados casos dará erro.

Como solucionar? Você deve considerar sempre o contexto da sua aplicação ao compor os links, de forma a ter sempe o link completo ao seu recurso, fazendo com que a referência seja direta ao recurso e não relatativa, na mesma pasta, etc. Para fazer isto você pode fazer de várias formas, como estas:

- JSTL: caso esteja usando JSTL você pode fazer algo assim:

```xml
<!-- recupera caminho do contexto e configura uma variável com este valor -->
<c:set var="ctx" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}" scope="request" />

<!-- usa a variável -->
<a href="${ctx}/site/pagina.jsp" />
```

- Usando JSP *scriptlet*: caso não esteja usando JSTL, você pode fazer algo menos amigável, recuperando mais ou menos assim:

```xml
<!-- recupera caminho do contexto e configura uma variável com este valor -->
<%
String ctx = request.getContextPath();
%>

<!-- usa a variável -->
<a href="<%=ctx%>/site/pagina.jsp" />
```

Ou diretamente:

```xml
<a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/site/pagina.jsp" />
```

Comment: É um projeto de estudo mesmo!

Aqui vai o link.

http://www.funerariasaopedro.net.br/imwsaogotardo.zip

Se puder dar uma olhada agradeço!

No caso, terei que usar <%=request.getContextPath() %>    para compor todos os links.

É isso?

Comment: @CarlosRocha isso, uma das abordagens citadas. Teste e me avise, que se precisar olho seu projeto. Ou você pode incluir uma página de exemplo na sua pergunta.

Comment: Será que não existe uma forma de usar tipo um filtro ou algo assim?

Comment: @CarlosRocha não vejo como um filtro seria uma boa alternativa. O que ele faria? Mesmo assim você pode usar, se achar que resolve

Comment: Adicionei a página de erro na pergunta. Pensei assim: Como o filtro pega todo o site, logo em todas as subpastas do sistema ele estaria. Então, os links não falhariam. Se voce pegar meu projeto verá que na pasta admin tem um filtro que varre a pasta e tem uma servlet também. Com esse filtro, qualquer que seja a página que não exista, a erro404.jsp abre normalmente.

Mas na pasta forumebd, não tem  nenhum filtro e as paginas inexistentes dentro dela ocorre o erro!

Comment: @CarlosRocha a abordagem citada soluciona seu problema, teste e veja se atende. Se quer um filtro para isto, construa-o e em caso de dúvidas inclua novas perguntas.

Comment: Sim amigo$, gostaria de saber também se esse é o padrão usado para solucionar esse caso. Ou seja é assim mesmo que o pessoal usa. Pois estou achando um pouco estranho usar context em todos os links. Se bem que parece não ter saida mesmo uma vez que a Servlet apenas redireciona corretamente páginas em seu nivel de hierarquia!

Comment: @CarlosRocha é sim, e não só em java. Se buscar por isto, encontrará inúmeras referências do pessoal usando.

Comment: Deixa eu perguntar só mais uma coisa e vamos fechar essa pergunta com a tua orientação?

É impressão minha ou o Dispatcher (Ou será a Servlet) trata links de estilos e imagens diferente de que trata links href'? Obrigado pelas orientações!

Comment: @CarlosRocha não entendi sua pergunta. Como assim trata diferente, diz referente ao resultado? Por que links são links, será sempre referência a um outro recurso, independente do tipo de recurso.

Comment: Veja no final da pergunta onde tem assim: A seguir erro404Conteudo.jsp.
Note que lá tem um href e um jsp include para o mesmo endereço. O Href, se clikado, vai corretamente. Mas o include diz que não achou o endereço (isso ainda no eclipse)

Comment: @CarlosRocha você está confundindo as coisas. O link é o acesso direto a um recurso já existente, um JSP já compilado, css, etc. O include faz, como o nome diz, a inclusão de um "sub-recurso" em tempo de compilação. Em `erro404Conteudo.jsp` não irá encontrar `_global/topoErro.jsp` para inclusão, pois não existe algo como `aa/_global/topoErro.jsp`, mas irá achar o link. Por que isto? Por que irá acessar a partir da raiz, então irá direto ao recurso. Para inclusões como está fazendo, use paths relativos. No caso o link (`a`) se mantem, mas o include será algo como `../_global/topoErro.jsp`.

Comment: Bom, Acho que consegui. Nos includes não foi preciso, mas nas imagens, nos hrefs e nos estilos das páginas que receberam Dispatcher foi necessário utilizar o context: ${pageContext.request.contextPath}.

Atualizei lá. Puder dar uma olhada para ver que esta correto. Coloquei o zip em http://www.funerariasaopedro.net.br/imwsaogotardo.zip.

Comment: @CarlosRocha legal, se foi útil, considere aceitar a resposta. Veja mais sobre a utilização da comunidade no tour e na seção de ajuda

Comment: Obrigado por tudo! No fim, acabei usando as orientações aqui coletadas!
Novamente, muto obrigado!

Comment: @CarlosRocha ok, caso tenha ajudado, considere aceitar a resposta. Se não, me avise para que eu possa editá-la. Além disto, veja o [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) e também a seção de ajuda, lá você entenderá o formato da comunidade. Vi que não aceitou nenhuma das perguntas em suas resposta até então, é interessante fazer uma visita nos dois links =)